# React Apex Charts Update options

Tags: reactjs, apexcharts, react-apexcharts

I am using apex chart and wanted to change the x-axis formatter function based on a state, but it is still using the first function passed to it when the component renders for the first time.

I was expecting it to use the other function when the state changes

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.